SLURM missing new slurmctld.log once the older is gziped
in the master node where slurmctl is installed it is not created the new slurmctld.log file once the older is gziped from the system.
Or I have to create it manually every time or is created after reboot of the PC. The log file has the below permitions:
-rw------- slurm slurm slurmctld.log

The slurm folder in /var/logs/ has permitions:
drwxr-xr-x slurm slurm 

in the slurm.conf I have:
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurm/slurmctld.log

Do you have any idea what I have to check?
Thanks

Slurm needs to be reloaded once the file has been zipped. So the logrotate configuration for the Slurm files  should contain something like
 /usr/bin/systemctl reload slurmctld.service

or
pkill -x --signal SIGUSR2 slurmctld

See the Slurm documentation on logging for more detailed information.

Thanks a lot damienfrancois! I created a new logrotate file taking the info from the slurm web site :)
